# Is there a way to compute oscillating iterated functions?

Tags: fixed-points, fractional-iteration

I've looked into iterated functions for a bit more than a year (especially thanks to tetration), but there's still things I do not quite know about them, especially when online searching isn't really concluent.

Just for you know, an iterated function is the function $F(x)$ defined as :

$F(X)=f^{\circ X}(x_0)=\underbrace{f(f(f(...x_0)))}_{X~times}$

Where $F^{\circ 0}(x_0)=x_0$

Such iterated functions are pretty easy to calculate if they have a fixed point, if they converge to a finite value. Thanks to Schroeder's equation :

For any function $f$, if you find a function $Ψ$ such that $Ψ(f(x))-τ = λ(Ψ(x)-τ)$, then $f^{\circ X}(x_0)=Ψ^{-1}((Ψ(x_0)-τ)λ^X+τ)$
(There are restrictions about what inverse function to use, and which $x_0$ you can chose but it's not the topic)

($τ$ and $λ$) are constants

In this case, with convergent iterated functions, $Ψ(x)=\lim_{n\to+\infty}({f^{\circ n}(x)})$, $τ$ is the fixed point the function converges to (with $x_0$ as the starting number), and $λ=f'(τ)$

But sometimes, the function doesn't converge, it doesn't have a fixed point. Actually, the double-iterated function $f(f(x))$ has 2 fixed points, so the iterated function oscillates between 2 values that converges.

In that case, I thought about calculating 2 different iterations, one by calculating the iterations of $f(f(x_0))$, and anoter by calculating the iterations of the same thing, but taking $f(x_0)$ as the starting number (basically decomposing the oscillation by its upper part and lower part, turning it into 2 new iterated functions that converge), and then by combining them with sines and cosines, but it wasn't concluent.

So if any of you know a "oscillating" version of Schroeder's equation, I'd be glad to hear it!

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: Pierre - I'll put my confusion with your question perhaps meaningfully in this words: do you ask for oscillating functions (like $\sin(x)$) when they are iterated, or do you ask about functions whose iterations (from a fixed starting value) show oscillating behaviour, say, have one ore more periodic points of order 2 (or more)?

Comment: Does perhaps this discussion match your question: http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/Base004.htm ?